# Linux POP v20 How do I remove all password requirements?

Tags: syntax

Goal: I want to skip all passwords requirements in my new distro Pop OS v21
I don't want to learn Linux I just want to use the end product.

How do I ask mister sudo, please skip all password dialog boxes?

Comment: Have you asked the source that posted the tutorial you're following what's going on?

Comment: @music2myear No, I didn't. Why ask for more help from bad advise?
  https://linuxconfig.org/configure-sudo-without-password-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux

Comment: First you need to look what "syntax error" means and then just search that entire error. It's a pretty simple and clear error. The "bad advice" probably isn't bad advice, just sayin'. Understanding what the computer is telling you is important to using it how you want.

Comment: @music2myear I see now, there are too many like you who rather criticize than be helpful. No wonder nobody want to use Linux.

Comment: No, you've come to a place where volunteers provide answers, expecting an answer, which isn't a bad thing. That's kinda the point here. We do ask, however, that you demonstrate the effort you've gone through, the research you've done, the things you've tried. This usually means doing a web search for the error message, reading a few of the top results, seeing if you can understand what you're being instructed. But when we ask you to do this you instead become argumentative. True, Linux can be a bit fiddly, but typing a command into Windows wrong will give you the same error.

Comment: @music2myear I don't want to learn Linux I want to just use it.

Comment: Then don't try to customize the system. If you just want to use something you must accept the rules of that system. This question indicates you wish to change those rules, which isn't a problem at all, but it means you have to learn the system in order to modify it the way you want. So either learn the system, or accept it as it comes.

Comment: @music2myear Windows it is.